# editing existing lines

Tags: arcgis-10.0, features, editing, line

I have a quick editing question.
 I have a main line (street) from which I want to extend other small lines to reach some points (manholes), but I want to keep just one feature (the main line). I can't use the extent tool, because it works only with line-line case.

ps: I am using ArcGis 10 (unfortunately;P )

Thanks,
Ligia

Comment: You say that you want to extend shorter lines from the main line to manholes, but only want to keep the mainline.  Please clarify what your goal actually is.  Are these lines supposed to be flowing from these manholes, and intersecting the main line in the street, or something different?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create a new feature (the short line from your street line to the manhole point). Then select both your new features and the street line a select "merge" from the editor drop down menu. It will prompt you to select which records attributes to keep. In your case you would keep the street line attributes. The result will be one feature for all your line work. I would be interested to know if there is a easier way to accomplish this.

Hope this helps,

Tyler

Comment: To clarify: from the main line (the duct in the street) I want to flow shorter lines to manholes ( on the sidewalk). I already have the duct and the manholes, so I want to create this short lines but I need them to be the same feature as the main line, not seperate features. I tries Tyler's way, but I receive the message :"the merge command could not be completed. Multipart edge features are not allowed"... still don't know how to do this task

Comment: I am getting the same error "Merge command could not be completed. Multipart edge features are not allowed." I have merged lines before with no issues, not sure what is happening now. Did anyone ever find a solution for this error message?

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog box asking you which feature's attributes to keep, uncheck the "Merge into a single COGO line" box.